# How we use widget in imagefield in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, imagefield

I want to use custom widget for `imagefield` in `django` form like  [here](http://olx.in/posting/).
I am also use crispy form if in crispy form it possible pls let me know how we can do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Checkout http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#an-image-clearable-input-with-thumbnail

Comment: Added link Fixed type Accent code words